# Spark GraphX pregel the number of iterations is greater than 3, resulting in FULL GC

Tags: scala, apache-spark, graph, garbage-collection

Spark GraphX  【pregel】 the number of iterations is greater than 3, resulting in FULL GC

The following is the specific implementation code

Spark - 2.4.5

```
def vprog(vid: VertexId, vdata: Set[(Int, ArrayBuffer[VertexId])], message: Set[(Int, ArrayBuffer[Long])]): Set[(Int, ArrayBuffer[VertexId])] = {
    
      message.filter(_._1 > 0) ++ vdata
    }


    def addMaps(spmap1: Set[(Int, ArrayBuffer[Long])], spmap2: Set[(Int, ArrayBuffer[Long])]): Set[(Int, ArrayBuffer[Long])] = {

      spmap1 ++ spmap2
    }


    def sendMsg(e: EdgeTriplet[Set[(Int, ArrayBuffer[Long])], _]): Iterator[(VertexId, Set[(Int, ArrayBuffer[VertexId])])] = {
      if (e.srcAttr.isEmpty) {
        Iterator.empty
      }
      else {
        val newAttr = e.srcAttr
          .filter(!_._2.contains(e.dstId))
          .map(lineData => {
            (lineData._2.length, lineData._2 :+ e.dstId)
          })
        Iterator((e.dstId, newAttr))
      }
    }


    val graph = atomicGraph.mapVertices((vid, value) => Set((0, ArrayBuffer(vid))))
    atomicGraph.unpersist(true)
  
    val initializeMessage: Set[(Int, ArrayBuffer[Long])] = Set((0, ArrayBuffer()))
  
    val resultGraph = graph.pregel(initializeMessage, totalDegree)(vprog, sendMsg, addMaps)
    println(resultGraph.vertices.collect().mkString("\n"))
```

### The program consumes a lot of time in GC

Number of vertices: 183

Number of edges: 2000+

```
Spark-submit:
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--num-executors 5 \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--driver-memory 20g \
--executor-memory 20g \
--executor-cores 10 \
--driver-cores 10 \
--conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=20g \
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=30g \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \
```

Comment: Calculate all paths of the N degree network